# LWJGL - OpenGL - Texture shading

Tags: opengl, textures, shaders, lwjgl, color

I want to use LWJGL to create a shader that all it does is change the color of the given texture. For example I tell it to draw the letter A using a sprite sheet then I can tell the shader to draw the letter in a certain color. How would you do something like this without needed to create different colored letter sprite sheets?

Task for the shader: Simply change all pixels to a certain color in the texture.
Input: Color , texture.
Output: it draws onto the screen the new colored texture.

How do i accomplish such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the shaders from the OpenGL ES Book Chapter 9 Sample as base [link](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/Android/Ch9_Simple_Texture2D/src/com/openglesbook/simpletexture2d/SimpleTexture2DRenderer.java).

First, I'll need a variable to pass the `vextex color` to the `vertex shader`. But I would also need to send this information to the `fragment shader` with a `varying` variable. Like this:

```
attribute vec4 a_color;
varying vec4 v_color;
```

Then, I'll just pass this information to the `fragment shader` from my `vertex shader`:

```
v_color = a_color;
```

In the `fragment shader`, where I would have the line `gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );`, I could just do something like:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ) * v_color;
```

So, if you have a texture with values `(1,1,1,1)`, and a `v_color` with values `(1,0,0,1)` (Red), it will result in `(1, 0, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fixed function OpenGL with GL lights, you need to tell it to modulate the base color (from glColor and lighting equations) with the texture:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

Otherwise, just multiply the vertex color by the texture color in the fragment shader.